# SSH tunneling NFS from remote to local error: address already in use

Tags: linux, ssh, nfs

I have a synology server behind an unconfigurable NAT, and a linux box behind a configurable NAT.  I want to establish an autossh tunnel to mount an NFS drive (shared by the synology box) on the linux box.

From the synology box, I execute the following:

```
autossh -v -M 0 -o "ServerAliveInterval 30" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -i /path/id_rsa -NL 2049:localhost:20049 user@linuxbox.com -p <forwarded_ssh_port>
```

However, I get the following error:

```
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:2049 forwarded to remote address localhost:20049
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 2049.
bind [::1]:2049: Address already in use
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 2049.
bind [127.0.0.1]:2049: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 2049
Could not request local forwarding.
```

Indeed (of course), NFS is listening on 2049 on the synology server:

```
user@synology:~$ netstat -plant|grep 2049
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Any thoughts on how to establish this tunnel, while avoiding the listening port conflict?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Your tunnel goes backwards: if the Linux server wants to mount the filesystem, then ssh on the Synology doesn't need to listen on *any* ports at all (why would it, if the *real* NFS service is already doing so).

Instead the tunnel's "listen" side needs to be on the Linux server (i.e. you want an SSH `-R` tunnel), which will then connect to the real NFS listener on the Synology.

```
ssh -R 22049:localhost:2049 user@linuxbox.com
```

(You also have the port specification backwards, too – the listening port goes first, the connect target last.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, think I solved it.  Instead of -L, I need to use -R:

```
autossh -v -M 0 -o "ServerAliveInterval 30" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -i /path/id_rsa -NR 2049:localhost:20049 user@linuxbox.com -p <forwarded_ssh_port>
```